# Multiple -e option to grep

Tags: grep

I want to pass multiple patterns to `grep`, and have a number of solutions of how to apply the `-e` option to each pattern.

The different patterns are stored in the array `ptrn`.   I wonder whether blanks in the array elements could be misinterpreted, as the `-e` would not be passed separately to the pattern.

The possibilities are

**Possibility 1**

```
mptrn=$( printf -- ' -e %s' "${ptrn[@]}" )
grep -E "$mptrn" -- "$flnm"
```

**Possibility 2**

```
for i in "${!ptrn[@]}"; do
  ptrn[$i]="-e ${ptrn[$i]}"
done
grep -E "${ptrn[@]}" -- "$flnm"
```

**Possibility 3**

```
eptrn=()
for i in "${!ptrn[@]}"; do
  eptrn+=("-e" "${ptrn[$i]}")
done
grep -E "${eptrn[@]}" -- "$flnm"
```

What could be the possible problems with any of the solutions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: If you'd tested these options, you'd see pretty quickly that (1) and (2) don't work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `ptrn=(" a b" " 333 22 1 ")`.

Answer 1:

```bash
mptrn=$( printf -- ' -e %s' "${ptrn[@]}" )
grep -E "$mptrn" -- "$flnm"
```

The entire output of the command will be assigned to `mptrn`, and the used format won't allow distinguishing between elements in the array if they contain space characters. `mptrn` will contain `-e  a b -e  333 22 1` (with both a leading and trailing space character). When executing `grep`, the quoted argument will be interpreted as a pattern argument because of the leading space, which will search for occurrences of `"$mptrn"` in the given files, which is not what you're trying to achieve. To make a similar approach work you can use the [`IFS`](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ifs-shell-variable) parameter.

```bash
[ "${IFS+x}" = x ] && OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$(printf '\x7f')
mptrn=$(printf "-e${IFS}%s${IFS}" "${ptrn[@]}")
# note that we don't use quotes
grep -E $mptrn -- "$flnm"
if [ "${OLD_IFS+x}" = x ]; then IFS=$OLD_IFS; else unset IFS; fi
```

---

Answer 2:

```bash
for i in "${!ptrn[@]}"; do
  ptrn[$i]="-e ${ptrn[$i]}"
done
grep -E "${ptrn[@]}" -- "$flnm"
```

This answer is close to the desired result, except that the searched patterns will include a leading space, which means the resulting command looks like this:

```bash
grep -E "-e  a b" "-e  333 22 1 " -- file
```

This can be solved by simply removing the space: `ptrn[$i]=-e${ptrn[$i]}`.

---

Answer 3:

```bash
eptrn=()
for i in "${!ptrn[@]}"; do
  eptrn+=("-e" "${ptrn[$i]}")
done
grep -E "${eptrn[@]}" -- "$flnm"
```

This answer is correct, the resulting `grep` command will be:

```bash
grep -E -e " a b" -e " 333 22 1 " -- file
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine them into one regex.  e.g. if you want to match any of the patterns, you can use the regex alternation operator `|` as an OR.

First, create a `join_by` function in bash:

```
join_by () { 
    local d="$1";
    shift;
    printf '%s' "$1";
    shift;
    printf '%s' "${@/#/$d}"
}
```

This is a fairly simplistic clone of `perl`'s built-in `join` function.  It uses the first arg as the delimiter, then all remaining args are joined using that delimiter, without an extra annoying leading or trailing delimiter.

Then use it like this:

```
$ p=(a b c d e)
$ re=$(join_by '|' "${p[@]}")
$ echo $re
a|b|c|d|e
```

You can $re with `grep -E` (alternation requires Extended Regular Expressions, "ERE").

```
grep -E "$re" filename
```

---

If you need to do more complicated boolean operations (e.g. `a && b && ! (c || d || e`) then use perl or awk.  bash is a terrible choice of language for data processing.

Comment: Reading the documentation it looks that `"-E"` option is only to allow Regex-ERE.  And one is still required to use `-e` for defining patterns as it is showing `-e PATTERN`.

Comment: `-e` is not required with grep unless you use multiple separate patterns.   `grep foo filename` is exactly the same as `grep -e foo filename`.   Also, `grep -e foo -e bar filename` is the same as `grep -E 'foo|bar' filename`.

Comment: And thus `mptrn=$(printf '|%s' "${ptrn[@]}") ; mptrn="${pa:1}" ; grep -E "$mptrn" filename` should be perfectly acceptable.  Correct?

Comment: close enough, assuming you meant `mptrn=${mptrn:1}` instead of `${pa:1}`. dunno where the $pa variable came from.

Comment: btw, I don't know if they make easy sense to you or not, but I find that the abbreviations you use (ptrn, flnm) make your code much harder to read - vowel-less words are readable but take more cognitive effort.  I'd advise using really short variable names (like p, mp, f) for temporary/"throw away" variables and full names (pattern, filename. pluralised if they're array vars) for variables that need to be in use for longer.